# Different ways to become shogun in Shogun 2 Total War

Tags: shogun-2-total-war

I know you can become shogun by capturing Kyoto and holding it for a year. Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there are no other ways of becoming shogun, and there is only one way of winning a scenario. Different victory conditions that you can chose of are present in Rome 2.